# indexes not populated in dr who sample database

Tags: neo4j

I downloaded the dr who neo4j sample database from here

http://www.neo4j.org/develop/example_data

I can traverse/query nodes, relationships, and properties.  But the indexes seem to be empty.

For example these cypher queries return no rows.

```
"START doctor = node:characters(character='Doctor') RETURN doctor"
"START doctor = node:characters('*:*') RETURN doctor"
"START actors = node:actors('*:*') RETURN actors"
```

How would I build the character index?  Is it:

```
Iterate all nodes
When node contains character property add it to index
```

Comment: what interface do you use for interacting with the data? is it the console, or shell, or some java rest?

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded a fixed dataset, the zip file didn't include the indexes subdirectory.

Those indexes are built manually in java-code of the drwho tutorial.

There is an index command in the shell which is also scriptable but it is not so easy to index the correct nodes.

I would probably either use the javascript integration with `eval` and create the indexes, iterate all nodes and according to the properties add the node to the appropriate index.

OR

I would use cypher to output the shell commands needed to index the nodes.

Something like

```
start n=node(*) where has(n.character) return "cd -a "+id(n)+" & index -i characters character ";
```

You'll have to remove the "I" from the table borders and replace the & with an && though.